# StreamReader ReadLine Memory Leak

Tags: c#, memory, tcpclient, tcplistener

I am making a server and I've noticed it has a bit of an odd memory leak. On my server, I have limited the total connections that one IP address can make to 8. This works perfectly.

However when I use LOIC to DoS my server, I notice that whilst it only creates8 instances of the network class, The ReadLine method of the StreamReader takes up a large portion of memory.

[image: An image of the VS Analyse]

I have verified using Console.WriteLine that no data is actually being received, it simply waits at that method. And the memory increases and fills up my entire 16GB.

Just to note, there are only ever 8 instances of this class from one IP and as I'm DoS'ing and not DDoS'ing it only ever comes from my IP(I have verified this).

What is the cause of this problem and how can I fix it ?

EDIT:
The relevant code is:

```
        string data;
        Dictionary<string, string> variables = null;
        try {

            while (_listen) {

                data = null;

                while ((data = _reader.ReadLine()) != null) {
```

Comment: If you don't send a newline (`\r\n`) then the line will keep increasing

Comment: @LucasTrzesniewski I don't choose what gets sent. It's a DoS attack that I'm running against my server.

Comment: I know, that was only an explanation of why the thing consumes memory. I was implying you shouldn't use `ReadLine` if you care about DoS attacks.

Comment: Ah okay, thank you. What would you recommend ?

Comment: I'll write an anwser.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `ReadLine` function will buffer the data into a string util it encounters a `\r\n` (`\n` alone won't do it). It uses a `StringBuilder` for that. So, if the data you receive doesn't contain the sequence `\r\n`, it'll end up allocating lots of memory for a single string.

You have one simple solution here: you have to limit the maximum string length your server is willing to read. This is required for dealing with malicious data - never trust the data you receive if your server may be the victim of DoS attacks.

So, the solution, as a `TextReader` extension method:

```
public static String ReadLineSafe(this TextReader reader, int maxLength)
{ 
    var sb = new StringBuilder();
    while (true) {
        int ch = reader.Read();
        if (ch == -1) break; 
        if (ch == '\r' || ch == '\n')
        { 
            if (ch == '\r' && reader.Peek() == '\n') reader.Read(); 
            return sb.ToString();
        } 
        sb.Append((char)ch);

        // Safety net here
        if (sb.Length > maxLength)
            throw new InvalidOperationException("Line is too long");
    }
    if (sb.Length > 0) return sb.ToString();
    return null; 
}
```

This is the original `ReadLine` code, with the added security check.

Oh, and you should wrap your `NetworkStream` in a `BufferedStream` for netowrk reads, in order to avoid calling `recv` on each byte.

Comment: Just a quick question. What if the length of data being received is unpredictable. Saying I have a user type in a description, if I specified 512 as the maxLength, would it read all of the 2048 bytes of data ?

Comment: Depending on your use case, you'd have to think about what is a reasonable upper limit for the data you expect to receive. For instance, a user is unlikely to type in 1 MB worth of text into a field. Then, add some safety margin and use that. But the limits you should set are application-specific. The function above won't read more than `maxLength` chars.

Comment: Right okay thank you. I shall use this code. I will mark it as the answer if it works okay.

Comment: I tried this method, and instead of just slowing my PC down and filling memory, it actually crashes it. Could that be caused by this method ?

Comment: Ignore my previous comment, it was a bug in my code not yours. Works great, this fixed the memory leak. Thanks

Comment: This is awesome, tnx! I had a file I'm reading that's 5GB size and it had 2GB of /0 chars.